Accelerating body with decreasing mass

Hello,
This is a high-school level question so the answer is obviously B by using F = ma with a constant force and decreasing mass.
However, if one considers the decreasing mass and F = dp/dt, things become messier.
Here's what I got so far:
F = dp/dt = mdv/dt + vdm/dt
F - vdm/dt = mdv/dt
(since the fuel is consumed at a constant rate, dm/dt is constant and m = m0(initial mass) - tdm/dt)
F - vdm/dt = (m0 - tdm/dt) * dv/dt
According to the question, F, dm/dt, and m0 are all constant.
After solving the differential equation, the v-t relationship is linear, meaning dv/dt or acceleration is constant, contradicting the answer of this question.
I'd really appreciate if you can give me some insights on this. Thank you!

The problem is in your solution to the differential equation - The DE does $not$ have a solution where v is linear in t.

Problem solved. dm/dt is negative so it's obvious in the first equation that dv/dt is increasing. Also, the sign in my differential equation is wrong.

according to your method
$$\frac {dv}{dt} =\frac {F-v \frac {dm}{dt}}{m} $$
The thing where you are going wrong is that Since $F$ is constant and the truck's mass is decreasing (because of  $dm/dt<0$), the effective force per unit mass increases as mass decreases. This is what causes the acceleration to increase.
Now $a$ can be expressed as $a=F/m(t)$  where, m(t) decreases as  fuel decreases
where $m(t) = m_o -t dm/dt$

The correct answer is B: "The truck's acceleration increases as the fuel is consumed."
In summary, as the mass m(t) decreases,$a=F/m(t)$ increases...so its not constant

Thank you for the clarification. I totally ignored the fact dm/dt is negative. I checked the differential equation, and indeed dv/dt is increasing. One question, since dm/dt is negative, the equation for m should be m(t) = m0 + tdm/dt, right？

plz accept the answer and upvote if u find it usefull

@XiaoDu the mass is decreasing so $-$ is only suitabe for m(t)
